# Cannot Edit values in textbox if i use "+" operator inside ng-model

Tags: angularjs

i have used ng-init to initialize the values for "firstName" and "LastName". Now if i set ng-model="firstName" or ng-model="lastName" then i can edit the vales in the Textbox.

But if i set ng-model as ng-model="firstName+lastName" then the vales get mapped but i am unable to edit it in the textbox.

Why is it so?

```
 <div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John';lastName='Doe'">
 <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
 <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName+lastName"></p>
 <p>You wrote: {{ firstName + lastName}}</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: You're not permitted to do this in AngularJS. Opening up the console and reading the error logs, Angular says `Expression 'firstName + lastName' is non-assignable.`

Comment: what are you expecting to do?

Comment: why are you doing this? why not just in the controller? $scope.name.first = 'Jhon'; $scope.name.last = 'Doe';

Comment: Actually i am new to angular so was just experimenting few things.Thanks for your comments guys.I have got the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your HTML

```
<div  ng-init="firstName='John';lastName='Doe'">
 <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
 <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"></p>
 <p>You wrote: {{ firstName + lastName}}</p>
 <p ng-init="fullname = firstName + lastName">Full Name: <input type="text" ng-model="fullname"></p>
 <p>You wrote: {{ fullname}}</p>
 </div>
```

Just create new scope object in `ng-init` or else you can initialise the scope object in your JS and use that as your `ng-model` to display in text box.